# Radio Buttons in Custom Notification

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to create a custom notification which contains radio buttons and a confirm button.

Displaying works, but when i click the "confirm" button, i want to trigger a pending intend with a BroadcastReciever *which somehow has the answer which radio button is currently selected*.

The only way i can do this is by giving each radio button a pending intend to the same BroadCast reciever. Which has a static field which stores the value of the last-pressed radio button (as all pending intents have a reference to a different BroadCast reciever instance).

Is there a better way to do this? it seems very error prone

Comment: There is no other way to handle radio button select. You can't get view from pending intent.

Comment: is there at least a better way to not have a "static" reference which button was pressed last? eg have all intents send to the same broadcast reciever instance?

Comment: Or is there a way to pass Parameters to the Broadcast listener?

Comment: You can send all required data with intent extras.

Comment: not really because the selected radio button is not known at the time creatinfg the intent :/